# How to specify the number of consumer on my DeadLetterQueues?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I've two different Camel webapp which is connected to an ActiveMQ's queues throught a JMS connection.

These two webapp are independents, they have differents queues, differents AMQ instance, but the JMS configuration is the same:

```
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="transacted" value="true" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTxManager" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER" />
</bean>
```

On one of my webapp's AMQ's manager I can see that my DLQ have 10 consumers as defined in the property *concurrentConsumers* whereas my other webapp has 0 consumers on its DLQ (but other queues have the 10 expected consumers).

**I thought that the *concurrentConsumers* parameter apply to every queues including automatically created DLQ**. How can I add consumers to automatically created DeadLetterQueues?

Comment: do you have any explicit configuration for your deadletter channel. If not try configuring and see how it works.

Comment: I doubt there is some configuration for this, but you can try creating consumers for queue 'ActiveMQ.DLQ' programmatically according to your requirement and verify if those listen correctly to the DLQ.